# Preview an Email template in lightning programmatically

Tags: lightning-aura-components, email-template

There's the publisher API that allows users to interact with Case Feeds in the Service Console.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/case_feed_dev_guide_component_interactions.htm

This allows me to do things like apply macros or send emails (after preview) programmatically.

I want to be able to do this in lightning. Does anyone have an approach ? Previewing the email template before sending is the biggest challenge i'm facing. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The Quick Actions API now allows you to perform actions like Publisher API - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/case_feed_dev_guide_intro.htm

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.